# Doctrine2 Cascade correct use

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Well, may be because it's monday, maybe because some people who I work with are messing with my brains, but I need to ask this totally newbie question that might solve some headaches...

Using Doctrine2 Mapping, we can set our cascade parameters in EntityManager and Database.

In this case, we have an `User` and `Client`. One `User` belongs to a `Client`, but one `Client` can have multiple `User`.

When we remove a `Client`, its `User`'s must be set `client_id` to `NULL`.

When we remove a `User`, it only removes that `User`.

`User entity`

```
manyToOne:
    client:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Client
        inversedBy: users
        joinColumn:
            name: client_id
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: SET NULL
        cascade: ["persist"]
```

`Client entity`

```
oneToMany:
    users:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\User
        mappedBy: client
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
```

This mapping, should be OK with the above cases using a `remove` from our EntityManager and a `DELETE` from our Databse, right?

We have another case, using `oneToOne` relations. In this case, we have a `Client` and a  `Shop` entity. One `Client`can only have one `Shop` and viceversa.

When we remove a `Client`, its `Shop` must be deleted too.

When we remove a  `Shop`, it must set to `NULL` its relation, but as we doesn't have the inversed side on `Shop`, nothing happens, we have it on `Client`, so it's `Shop` who has `client_id`.

`Shop entity`

```
oneToOne:
    client:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Client
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
        inversedBy: shop
        joinColumn:
            name: client_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

`Client entity`

```
oneToOne:
    shop:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Shop
        mappedBy: client
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
```

As far as I can tell, this mapping will break because it will remove the `Client` record when a `Shop` is removed, that should not happen because we only want the `Shop` to be deleted, not both.

And last, but not least important, we have a `oneToMany` unidirectional relation, which becomes a `manyToMany` with a join table, it may have an Entity with extra fields but we will use a simple relation.

`Client` has `Phones`, but as it's a `ManyToMany` relation, this means that n `Client` can have n `Phone` and viceversa with a join table named `client_has_phone`.

When we remove a `Phone` we want to remove that relation from our join table `client_has_phone`. Same happens when we remove a `Client`, that relation is gone forever.

`Client entity`

```
manyToMany:
    phones:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Phone
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
        joinTable:
            name: client_has_phone
            joinColumns:
                client_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
                    onDelete: CASCADE
            inverseJoinColumns:
                phone_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
                    onDelete: CASCADE
```

This mapping, should be OK in both EntityManager and Database.

I would like to give some advice on this, because I am sure that things works as I've explained above, but maybe I'm wrong and `Doctrine` documentation is not well explained (at least on this part).

And also, given the cases and example mappings, if there are errors, I would like to give a working code in order to improve our stuff and tell my coworkers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's three questions in one, but there you go:

1. `cascade=remove` will remove all `User`s of a `Client` being deleted, otherwise it seems OK
2. consider this:

`Shop entity`

```
oneToOne:
    client:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Client
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
        mappedBy: shop
```

`Client entity`

```
oneToOne:
    shop:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Shop
        inversedBy: client
        joinColumn:
            name: shop_id
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: SET NULL
        cascade: ["persist"]
```

now the DB's `ON DELETE` sets `NULL` when the `Shop` is deleted and Doctrine's `cascade=remove` will remove `Shop` when a `Client` is deleted.

3. seems OK to me